Using xtable to arrange multiple tables in a grid
My data has four columns: method name, statistic name, mu, CV, value, there are 216 rows. I would like to somehow create a table that looks like the following in LaTeX:
Can I use xtable to achieve this?
I have tried looking on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf but can't find the kind of table I want.
